# Need assistance with SQL Query with error message Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, mariadb, window-functions

Good Day

I have the following query but I'm getting an error message 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
UPDATE expenditure
SET BP = (
    SELECT * ,
           SUM(balance_provision - actual_amt_voucher) over (partition by voteid order by expenditureid) AS BalanceProvision
    FROM expenditure
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to update column `bp` with a window sum.

Your query fails because you are trying to assign a resultset (that has multiple columns) to a single column.

But even you were returning a scalar value from the subquery, this would not work, since MySQL does not allow reusing the target table of the `update` in a subquery.

Instead, yo can use the `update ... join` syntax. Assuming that `expenditureid` is the primary key of the table, as its name suggests, that would be:

```
update expenditure e
inner join (
    select 
        expenditureid, 
        sum(balance_provision - actual_amt_voucher) over (partition by voteid order by expenditureid) bp
    from expenditure
    group by expenditureid
) e1 on e.expenditureid = e1.expenditureid
set e.bp = e1.bp
```

Comment: Thank you. Much Appreciated!